# Stronger scientific word than 'increased'

Tags: word-choice

I am writing a computer engineering paper and try to express that our system increased a certain value fairly much, emphasizing that the amount of increase is uncommon. Could anyone recommend a **word** to *imply* 'increased a value fairly much' in a scientific way?

---

First of all, sorry for making you confused, but actually I was composing a presentation which is about my research project. I just mentioned it as 'writing a paper', which I thought uses similar terms to when composing a research presentation. Anyway..

Our project is making an custom chip accelerating deep-learning, and in this field, people commonly regards that the more the accelerator contains the neuron data, the better the system is. My original intention was making one short phrase which emphasizes the *increased* number of neuron data, such as '*Increased number of neuron data*', but I thought this phrase is somewhat weak to emphasize the *increase* itself.

Comment: I meant the number of variables which our system can accommodate, and the more variables the system can accommodate, the better the system is.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence where you would like this word to be used?

Comment: *increased it **substantially*** . . . But vague terms like this are frowned on in technical papers; you would do better to provide a meaningful quantity such as *increased it by 33%*.

Comment: How about using _augmented_ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a technical article in a technical context, then we'd probably stick with boring, dispassionate and objective terms, and quantify them where necessary. So you'd say "large increase" or "significant increase" or (probably best) "observed an increase of XX% to YY% percent". When your story gets picked up by the popular media, they can decided to say "skyrocketed" or "exploded" or "boosted" or whatever else they think will keep eyes on their page.

Comment: Turns out that this is exactly what I do now. Thanks :)

Comment: Only after I posted this answer did I see that StoneyB had put essentially identical advice in as a comment on the question. Honestly didn't mean to plagiarize from them; would have mentioned that comment had I seen it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert in science, but for a huge growth in number, I am currently thinking of the word "proliferated."

Also, I think there might be more to what you want to express.  For example, you are more leaning towards producing more data in a faster manner, how about the word "expedited"?

Comment: Tipically, in my language proliferation has a negative connotation. We would talk about nuclear weapons proliferation, bacteria proliferation, etc., but not, say, sales proliferation. What would be the situation in English?

Comment: Proliferation seems more active and widespread than this, which is a discrete "we made a chip that holds more data."

Answer (score 2):

You can use the verb **boost**, or the idiomatic **breakthrough** to describe the improvement.

Comment: Actually, I though the term 'breakthrough', but I thought I could be seen somewhat exaggerated.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider ***quantum jump*** (or *quantum **leap***). This is defined as:

> **[quantum jump](https://www.google.com/search?q=meaning%20of%20quantum%20jump)** (*noun*) a huge, often sudden, increase or change in something

---

#### Usage warnings:

1) The phrase also has a very specific and more formal meaning in the realm of physics. While this phrase does have a scientific ring to it – which is what the O.P. asked for – I'd be careful using it in a physics paper.

2) If you are going to say that your system made a quantum leap for a certain value, be prepared to show hard data that shows what you mean, and exactly how much it increased.

---

#### Footnote:

In computer science, the terms ***exponential growth*** and ***increased by an order of magnitude*** are often used, but, again, you'd better be sure the actual performance increase mirrors the phrase you use. (I wouldn't use "order of magnitude" in a computer science paper unless the performance had increased by a factor of ten, for example.)

Comment: Note, exponential growth always refers to a specific pattern of increase over time, not a one-time change in value.

Comment: No, "quantum leap" does not by any mean describe  a huge jump in scientific writing. It might work in advertisement language

Comment: @laugh  agreed, it's the kind of exaggeration commonly used in television commercials and techie magazines, but it doesn't work for a formal scientific paper (unless specifically talking about physics).

Comment: To the downvoters: Good clarifications and I concur. These might work as words with a "scientific ring" ring to them in non-technical contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide a detailed example-sentence with "increase", I would like to mention three things generally.

First, as you asked for a verb, I suggest using the verb **[augment](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/augment)** which simply means increase; It sounds formal. The following example is also from the Cambridge dictionary:

> *He would have to find work to augment his income.*

Second, using the corresponding nouns:

> *Our system brings about a significant increase in a certain value.*

Third, using verbs with positive connotations like **Improve**, **Enhance**, or the corresponding nouns like **improvement**, **enhancement**, etc. However, you should modify the sentence in such way that the result or the final impact is projected. For instance,

> *Our system improved the parameter X significantly.*

Answer (score 0):

I Like engorged

> cause to swell with blood, water, or another fluid.
>   "the river was engorged by a day-long deluge"

"the accelerator was engorged with more neuron data then possible previously, perhaps by a magnitude of 2 or more."

It's a little awkward, but that is a great tool, to get attention and draw emphasis. Just the visual image of a water balloon filled to busting with all that awesome neuron data. People should pay attention, even if just a little bit more.